# mongo $project not projecting original values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new to Mongodb, and NoSQL in general and I am trying to use mongodbs aggregate function to aggregate data from one collection to be inserted into another. An example of the original collection would be this:

**Original Collection**

`{
    supplier: 'aldi',
    timestamp: '1492807458',
    user: 'eddardstark@gmail.com',
    hasBeenAggregated:false,
    items:[{
        name: 'butter',
        supplier: 'aldi',
        expiry: '1492807458',
        amount: 454,
        measureSymbol: 'g',
        cost: 2.19
    },{
        name: 'milk',
        supplier: 'aldi',
        expiry: '1492807458',
        amount: 2000,
        measureSymbol: 'ml',
        cost: 1.49
    }]
}`

An example of the output I am trying to achieve would be:

**New Collection**

`{
    user:'eddardstark@gmail.com',
    amount: 3.68,
    isIncome: false,
    title: 'food_shopping',
    timestamp: '1492807458'
}`

The aggregation function that I am using is:

**Aggregation**

`var result = db.runCommand({
    aggregate: 'food_transactions',
    pipeline: [
        {$match: {hasBeenAggregated: false}},
        {$unwind: '$items'},
        {$group:{_id: '$_id',amount:{$sum: '$items.cost'}}},
        {$project: {
            _id:0,
            user:1,
            amount:1,
            isIncome: {$literal: false},
            title:{$literal: 'food_shopping'},
            timestamp:1
        }}
    ]
});
printjson(result)`

This aggregation function does not return the `user` or `timestamp` fields. Instead, I get the following output:

**Output**

`{
    "amount" : 3.6799999999999997,
    "isIncome" : false,
    "title" : "food_shopping"
}`

If I don't group the results and perform the calculations in the `$project` stage, the fields are all projected correctly, but obviously, there is a new document created for each sub-document in the `items` array and that rather defeats the purpose of the aggregation.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `$group` pipeline to include all the fields you wish to project further down the pipeline.

To include user field you can use `$first`

```
{$group:{_id: '$_id', user:{$first:'$user`}, amount:{$sum: '$items.cost'}}},
```

Additionally, if you are 3.4 version you can simplify your aggregation to below.

Use `$reduce` to sum all the `item`'s cost in a single document. For all documents you can add `$group` after `$reduce`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
        {$match: {hasBeenAggregated: false}},
        {$project: {
            _id:0,
            user:1,
            amount: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$items",
                initialValue: 0,
                in: { $add : ["$$value", "$$this.cost"] }
              }
            },
            isIncome: {$literal: false},
            title:{$literal: 'food_shopping'},
            timestamp:1
        }}
    ])
```